# Enable .htaccess in Ubuntu 14.10, Apache/2.4.10

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I'm trying to enable .htacces in Ubuntu 10.14, but saw when configuring the new version of the Apache / 2.4.10 how to set up 'and different from previous ones.

I'm putting the files in / var / www /

I tried already but I am not managing to make it work.

**apache2ctl -S:**

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

**000-default.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    <Directory "/var/www/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: How do you know that is not enabled? how do you determinate that?

Comment: It does not work, you are entitled to, but the correct setting'm not getting @LeaTano

Comment: Can you just write in the `.htaccess` some `$` character and let me know if you get a 500 error or nothing? (I am trying to troubleshoot your application)

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL http://localhost/arquibancada/login was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: you need to load the rewrite module I think you did not enable the write module `a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: return: sudo a2enmod rewrite: Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: do you have something like this in your htaccess? `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /`

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]

Comment: See what your error log says. Also put some random text at the top of your .htaccess, if it gives you 500 error, then .htaccess is being read otherwise if the site still loads its not.

Comment: do you find the answer ? @user3092202